# How do I print a sentence for an assigned output/input?

Tags: python, string, input, output

I have a code that allows a user to choose between 3 options
Ie; Beginner: 1, Intermediate: 2 and Advanced: 3.
However, I'm wanting to generate a paragraph that's assigned to each of the 3 options.
For example
If the user has entered 1 for Beginner, the output will follow with "Hi Beginner! We are going to learn about ....."

The code I've tried thus far is just using the print(" ")option followed by 
if f==0:
print("You have entered " + str(inp) + ": " + out). 
However, as I'm writing a long paragraph, the output is messy.

Comment: Have you tried newline `\n` to break your text into lines?

Comment: Hi, yes I have. Additionally, I have tried f==0: print("Hi Beginner.... + str(inp) + ": " + out) and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Well, i think that you're printing a line without using "\n" in your print text, that's why the output will be always a entire line. 
You can use "\n" to write different lines:

```
print("This is a line\nNow this is other")
```

Or you can use triple quotes:

```
print("""This is a line
Now this is other""")
```

Comment: I'll try it again. I must have been doing something wrong with the quotation marks! Thanks.